# Firebase RT returns 4 objects but only 3 are available

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

If there is anything I could add to assist please let me know. Trying to obtain the key for the items, but trying to first tackle retrieving the data and displaying it.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  coursesRef: AngularFireObject<any>;
  courses: Observable<any>;

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.coursesRef = db.object('/courses');
    this.courses = this.coursesRef.valueChanges();

    this.courses.subscribe(course => console.log(course));
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let course of courses | async">
    {{ course | json }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

this returns a 4 objects although the database only contains 3.

[image: Returned values]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is that the object should be called in the ngOnInit function.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  coursesRef: AngularFireList<any>;
  courses: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.coursesRef = db.list('/courses');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.courses = this.coursesRef.valueChanges();

    this.courses.subscribe(course => console.log(course));
  }
}
```